# Cordova project in netbeans cannot display library js in the table

Tags: android, apache, cordova, netbeans, web

I tried to create a new Cordova project in netbeans and when the step comes where I have to select the required JS from the table I tried to add the new two JS. But the it showed some network error and asked me to configure the proxy. But then I updated the entire lib and now the table does not show any lib files instead show it to be loading.

Comment: Can you add some screen shots. Did you check your network connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your cache directory and restart NetBeans. You can find location of cache dir in Help->About in NetBeans. If it won't help, you need to also remove your user dir.

Btw this JS library management has been completely rewritten for upcoming NetBeans 8.1. The "Update" action in your NetBeans is very slow and time consuming. Try the NetBeans dev build from [here](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/). It has much better support for JS libraries management (including npm and bower)